# Can the multiplicative group of invertible residue classes mod $105$ be generated by $2$ residue classes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/{105})^*$ has $48$ elements. I've tried (and failed) to find two elements in it to generate the group. Of course it is not cyclic, no primitive roots. I made  the same attempt for integers mod $30$ (again no primitive root) and did find two elements that generate in that case. If there's things known about general $n$ having no primitive root I'd also appreciate a reference/link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem says that $\Bbb Z_{105}\cong \Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_7$ because $105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$. The group of units in $\Bbb Z_{105}$ is similarily isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_3)^*\times (\Bbb Z_5)^*\times (\Bbb Z_7)^*\cong \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_6$. This group cannot be generated by two elements. An idea for a proof is to take two candidate generators, consider which entries are even and odd, and seeing that you can't reach all possible even-or-odd combinations of elements in that group.

In contrast, $\Bbb Z_{30}\cong \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_5$, and if we look at the unit group here, the first factor becomes trivial, and we basically only have $(\Bbb Z_3)^*\times (\Bbb Z_5)^*$. Both those factors are cyclic, so we can get the whole group with only two generators.

Comment: Thanks much for this (general) answer.